# What is Geun-se (the man in the cellar) messaging to Da-song, the Park family's son?

Tags: translation, parasite

In *Parasite* (2019), Geun-se is the man living beyond the Park's house. He communicates with Morse code through the lamps above the stairs. In the last act, he uses this technique, but only the Park's son, Da-song, sees it from his tent in the garden. Being "fluent" in Morse code, he writes the message down and it is later briefly seen, but never addressed again.

Since I can't read Korean, my question is, what was Geun-se communicating and/or what did Da-song write down?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't see the full message being typed out, because part of the scene shows him pressing the button.  However, based on the button pressing and actual light scenes, it looks like he is spelling out the name of Mrs. Kim (the new house cleaner/mother of the poor family).

<sub>Source: My wife is Korean.</sub>